How to use JITO bundles to send 2 JUPITER SWAP V6 transactions?
So, I try to send two Jupiter Swap API V6 transactions faster and atomically. I heard that JITO is the best feature for my needs. However, I NEVER been able to land a bundles with JITO. It always goes Invalid, Pending and Failed without any explanation. Wonder if I have something wrong with my code? I'm stuck and LLM doesnt help.. Any help would be much appreciated!
This is my Jupiter transaction code:
const processRoute = async (route, wallet) => {
try {
const result = await getTransaction(route);
if (!result || !result.swapTransaction) {
  console.error("No swapTransaction found for route:", route);
  return;
}
let transaction;
try {
  transaction = VersionedTransaction.deserialize(
    Buffer.from(result.swapTransaction, "base64")
  );
} catch (legacyError) {
  try {
        transaction = Transaction.from(
      Buffer.from(result.swapTransaction, "base64")
    );
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error deserializing transaction:", error);
    return;
  }
}
transaction.sign([wallet.payer]);
const serializedTransaction = transaction.serialize();
return serializedTransaction;
} catch (error) {
console.error("Error processing route:", error);
}
};

This is my "tip JITO" code:
const tipJito = async () => {
try {
const tipAccount = new PublicKey(
  "ADaUMid9yfUytqMBgopwjb2DTLSokTSzL1zt6iGPaS49"
);
const tip = 100_000;

const { blockhash, lastValidBlockHeight } =
  await connection.getLatestBlockhash();

const transferInstruction = SystemProgram.transfer({
  fromPubkey: wallet.publicKey,
  toPubkey: tipAccount,
  lamports: tip,
});

const message = new TransactionMessage({
  payerKey: wallet.publicKey,
  recentBlockhash: blockhash,
  instructions: [transferInstruction],
}).compileToV0Message();

const transaction = new VersionedTransaction(message);

transaction.sign([wallet.payer]);

const serializedTransaction = transaction.serialize();
return serializedTransaction;
} catch (error) {
console.error("Error in tipJito:", error);
}
};

this is my "sending bundle" code:
const sendTxJito = async (serializedTxs) => {
const delay = (ms) => new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
try {
const bundle58 = serializedTxs.map((value) => bs58.encode(value));
const response = await axios.post(
  "https://mainnet.block-engine.jito.wtf/api/v1/bundles",
  {
    jsonrpc: "2.0",
    id: 1,
    method: "sendBundle",
    params: [bundle58],
  }
);
const bundleId = response.data.result;
let bundleCheckLoop = true;
while (bundleCheckLoop) {
  const getInflightBundle = await axios.post(
    "https://mainnet.block-engine.jito.wtf/api/v1/bundles",
    {
      jsonrpc: "2.0",
      id: 1,
      method: "getInflightBundleStatuses",
      params: [[bundleId]],
    },
    { timeout: 30000 }
  );

  if (getInflightBundle.data.result.value[0].status === "Failed") {
    console.log(
      `Bundle failed to sent! ${getInflightBundle.data.result.value[0].bundle_id}`
    );
    bundleCheckLoop = false;

    return false;
  } else if (getInflightBundle.data.result.value[0].status === "Landed") {
    console.log(
      `Bundle sent successfully! ${getInflightBundle.data.result.value[0].bundle_id}`
    );
    bundleCheckLoop = false;

    return true;
  } else if (
    getInflightBundle.data.result.value[0].status === "Invalid" ||
    getInflightBundle.data.result.value[0].status === "Pending"
  ) {
    console.log(
      `Waiting confirmation! status: ${getInflightBundle.data.result.value[0].status}. Id: ${getInflightBundle.data.result.value[0].bundle_id}`
    );
    await delay(2000);
  }
}
} catch (error) {
console.log(error);
}
};

Finally, my main() code:
  const firstTransaction = await processRoute(sourceToTarget, wallet);
  const secondTransaction = await processRoute(targetToSource, wallet);
  const tippingJito = await tipJito();

  const bundleTransactions = [
    firstTransaction,
    secondTransaction,
    tippingJito,
  ];

  const bundle = await sendTxJito(bundleTransactions);

Thank you so much!
